# Running two meteor apps in the same aws instance on two different sub-domains using Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have two Meteor Apps deployed in the same AWS EC2 instance. One of them running on port 80 and the other which is the admin app running on port 8000. Both share the same local MongoDB. Now I want to create a sub-domain like `dashboard.myapp.com` and point it to `myapp.com:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dns record pointing to your AWS EC2 instance, install nginx and configure it to redirect all request to `dashborad.myapp.com` to port 8000 and the other to port 80.